# Ordered List and PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, html-lists

Good morning!

I have a (I think) basic Html - PHP question that after hours of attempts I can't seem to get right.

I have a page, that using JqueryUI gridsort. On the page, The user can upload pictures from their PC to their web folder. The pictures are then ahref'd inside of a drag and drop UL.

for each image that is uploaded I do this ( i do have the UL declared avoid, and closed below)

```
    $imgID++;


echo '<li class="ui-state-default"><img id="'.$imgID.'"'.' src="user_files/'.$file_name.'" draggable="true" height="90" width="95"></li>';
```

This create the drag and drop picture based on the amount of files that they upload, and allows them to visual reorganize them. in top left to bottom right order. What I would like to do is be able to return the order that the images are in. I toyed with the $imgID++  for assigning each image an ID, hoping that would help.

My question is - How can I return the order of the lists so that I can process it. (i.E ill probalby put into SQL, or most likely XML.)

Thanks!

Comment: you use DOM to get the `<li>` children of the parent `<ul>` (or `<ol>`). What you get out of the DOM tree will represent the order they're being presented in on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer would be to loop through the images in the ul assuming there is nothing else in the list than the li and image tags

```
var listofIDs = [];
$('ul li').each(function(){
    listofIDs.push($(this).find('img').prop('id));
});
$.ajax{[
    url:'example.com',
    data: {'list':listofIDs},
    type: 'post'
]}.done(function(msg){alert(msg);});
```

Also you should use a database idnum as the id and not just an incrementer so it is an easy column update.  Make a column called image_order and when you update the images in your ajax script set the order based on the image Id's

Comment: Looks like a good answer, I'm not familiar with Ajax strangely enough. I will try this. If I'm reading this right, it will post  a list of the ID's in order?

Comment: That is the plan, of course change example.com with the path to the php file you have that will insert into your database. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

Jquery - sortable (on update make an ajax call with the serialiaze order)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lista-prova").sortable({
      handle : '.trascinabile',
      update : function () { 
        var ordina = $('#lista-prova').sortable('serialize');
        $("#info").load("riordinamento.php?"+ordina);
      }
    });
});
```

and this the update php code

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET['oggettoItem'] as $position => $item) :
    $sql[] = "UPDATE `table` SET `position` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
endforeach;

print_r ($sql);
?>
```

this is the html of the sortable item

```
<div id="info">In attesa di aggiornamento post-riordinamento</div>
<div id="lista-prova">
    <li id="oggettoItem_1"><img src="arrow.png" width="48" height="48" class="trascinabile" /><strong>Oggetto 1</strong></li>
    <li id="oggettoItem_2"><img src="arrow.png" width="48" height="48" class="trascinabile" /><strong>Oggetto 2</strong></li>
    <li id="oggettoItem_3"><img src="arrow.png" width="48" height="48" class="trascinabile" /><strong>Oggetto 3</strong></li>
    <li id="oggettoItem_4"><img src="arrow.png" width="48" height="48" class="trascinabile" /><strong>Oggetto 4</strong></li>
</div>
```